# Can I leave the UK with a non-UK passport

Tags: uk, dual-nationality, customs-and-immigration

I am a UK citizen and I also have a Canadian passport. I am in the process of applying for a work visa in the US with my UK passport. I have an upcoming trip in Europe (I am currently in the UK). My question is: Will I be able to leave the UK with my Canadian passport (as I didn't enter the UK with my Canadian passport)? I'm slightly concerned there might not be time between getting back my passport from the US Embassy and my travel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK does not have exit border checks, so you do not have to show your passport to anybody.

You do have to show a passport to the airline operating the plane you are boarding (or train or boat operator), but that is solely to prove you have the right to enter the destination country. They do not care about the country you are leaving, and certainly not about how you entered it. Any passport that will get you into the destination is acceptable.

As a UK national I have entered and exited the UK on a Canadian passport many times.

Comment: Have you exited the UK on a Canadian passport after entering it with the UK one, though? The UK reconciles exit records with entry records.  I suppose this wouldn't cause a problem for someone ddeparting under these circumstances, but I don't know that for certain.  It might.

Answer (score 2):

My kid has a dual citizenship, Austrian and Russian. When we leave Austria for Russia, we show the Russian passport at the norder. When we travel back to Austria, we show the Austrian passport.
So in your case you'll probably have no issue at all with leaving the UK with your Canadian passport (depending on where you're going, though), but how are you going to come back later?

Comment: How? Walk up to the border checkpoint and claim to be a UK citizen.  Realistically they will detain you and check it out using whatever resources they can get their hands on. The more you help the faster it goes. You may get a tongue lashing for not entering on your UK passport, but if you have explained "The US embassy hasn't given it back yet", probably not even.

Comment: @Harper the other option, of course, is to have someone send the UK passport to you while you're out of the country.

Comment: When your child leaves Austria showing a Russian passport, doesn't the passport officer ask about his authorization to be in Austria?

Comment: @phoog, no, they don't. Been travelling like that for 8+ years and always had to show only the passport that proves the eligibility to enter the destination country.